# Kotlin Coroutines Run Out of Order

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I am writing an Android Jetpack Compose mobile app in Kotlin. I am having a lot of problems with coroutines. I am using shared preferences, so I need to call those suspend functions in a coroutine scope. I am new to coroutines, and I obviously don't understand them well.

**I have an option, that I am saving in an Android DataStore, to bypass the splash screen when the app starts up. I also have a checkbox on the splash screen to bypass the screen from now on. I need to be able to check the option when the splash screen would be displayed, but also to allow the checkbox to be changed if it does display. And I eventually want to have a hamburger menu to set this and other options. Since DataStore operations are async, I am forced to deal with suspend routines.**

Here is my caller, **which is where I am trying to decide whether to bypass the splash screen or not** :

```
var shouldBypassSplashScreen: Boolean = false
runBlocking {
    val job = launch {
        shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
    }
    job.join()
}
LogHelper.logDebug("${MODULE_NAME}.$FUNCTION_NAME: shouldBypassSplashScreen = $shouldBypassSplashScreen")
```

Here is the called function, in my **`MainViewModel` (sorry, bolding is not working below, but I've added the first two lines below)**:

```
**
var bypassSplashScreenOpt: MutableLiveData<Boolean>
        = MutableLiveData(false)
    private set
**
...
    suspend fun isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked(): Boolean {
        val FUNCTION_NAME = "isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()"
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userPrefRepo.shouldBypassSplashScreen().collect {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME.$FUNCTION_NAME: bypassSplashScreenOpt.value = ${bypassSplashScreenOpt.value}, it = $it")
                    bypassSplashScreenOpt.value = it
                }
            }
        }
        return bypassSplashScreenOpt.value!!
    }
```

I have tried many different things, but no matter what I do, the log message that comes after I call the function is always showing up before the one in the called function. And the problem is that my boolean is always false in the calling function, because it doesn't seem to be waiting until the caller is run.

==============

UPDATE:

First of all, thanks to you folks who replied to my question. I realize now how little I understand coroutines. I obviously need to read up on them and try to wrap my head around it. Even looking at your suggestions seems kind of beyond me now.

In trying not to put too much code in my original post, I realize I didn't give enough context on what I was trying to do. So I have updated my original post above, the new info is in **bold text**.

All I am really trying to do here is have options in a DataStore, that I can set from a screen, and check in my logic. Since reading the data from a DataStore is an asynchronous event, I just need to be able to wait until it gets the data back before I can check, display, or set that data. That doesn't seem like that should be that complicated, but it obviously is.

I changed the function in my MainViewModel based on Tenfour04's initial response, and that part works.

```
    suspend fun isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked(): Boolean {
        return userPrefRepo.shouldBypassSplashScreen().first()
    }
```

From everything I've read, I totally agree with your comment that I should not be using `runBlocking`. However, I am totally puzzled why this compiles:

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
    }
}
```

But this tells me that `launch` is undefined when I compile it:

```
launch {
    shouldBypassSplashScreen = mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
}
```

That's really the only reason I'm using `runBlocking`, because I can't get past the compile errors without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution that can fix this bug. You see only the default state value in the log because you're trying to launch a coroutine directly inside the composition context instead of using an [effect handler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Let's start by changing the code inside the ViewModel:

```
// A mutable state flow holding the value.
private val _isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked = MutableStateFlow(false)
val isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked = _isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked.asStateFlow()

// Observe the value from the repository.
private fun getBypassSplashScreenOptChecked() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        userPrefRepo.shouldBypassSplashScreen().collect { isOptChecked ->

            // Update the state value
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME shouldBypassSplashScreen: $isOptChecked")
                _isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked.update { isOptChecked }
            }

        }
    }
}

// Start observing the value from the repository
// when the ViewModel is created.
init {
    getBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()
}
```

And finally the Composable:

```
// Collect the state value from the ViewModel
val isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked by viewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked.collectAsState()

// Log the value whenever it changes
LaunchedEffect(key1 = isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked) {
    LogHelper.logDebug("$MODULE_NAME shouldBypassSplashScreen: $isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked")
}
```

To learn more information about states in Compose you can visit [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) link.

Comment: You could use `stateIn` to reduce all that ViewModel code you have to two lines with absolutely no change in behavior. All the dispatcher swapping is completely unnecessary as well.

Comment: Thanks, for your answers. I have updated my original post with some added context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked()` function is that instead of doing any suspending work, it fires off some new, unrelated coroutine asynchronously, doesn't wait for that coroutine, and just returns the current value of the variable before that other coroutine has even started.

It's a suspend function, so it can only conceivably get the most recent value of the flow at the time you call it. It doesn't make sense to fully collect it, so call `first()` on it instead.

Assuming that `userPrefRepo.shouldBypassSplashScreen()` returns a Flow and it works correctly, the correct implementation of this function would be:

```
suspend fun isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked(): Boolean {
    return userPrefRepo.shouldBypassSplashScreen().first()
}
```

I don't know what `bypassSplashScreenOpt` is that you're also messing with on the side. If you aren't using it elsewhere, just delete it.

Your code in the Composable is pretty nasty. You should avoid calling `runBlocking` ever, but especially in a Composable, because that means it's going to block for some long-running action every time there's a recomposition.

*Incidentally, it makes no sense that you launch a coroutine and immediately `join()` it. The correct implementation of that code (if it were not a terrible idea to use `runBlocking` in a Composable) would be `val shouldBypassSplashScreen = runBlocking { mainViewModel.isBypassSplashScreenOptChecked() }`*

---

So, since it will take a moment to retrieve this value, and you should avoid blocking in your composition, there are a few different strategies you could use. Here's just one suggestion:

Since it probably won't take more than a second, just show a blank screen in your composable until you determine whether to show the splash screen. So you complete your composition without blocking and the main thread won't be frozen, which makes your app and the device seem janky.

Use a launched effect to run this one time when it first composes your entry point composable. There's no need to re-run it when a recomposition happens. For one thing, there's nothing in this composition that would cause it to recompose, but also, you're just waiting for the first value to arrive and then navigating away from this composition.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    if (userPrefRepo.shouldBypassSplashScreen()) {
        navController.nagivate("main")
    else {
        navController.nagivate("splash")
    }
}
// Just don't have anything displayed in this entry point composable.
```

Comment: Thanks, @tenfour04, for your answer. I have updated my original post with some added context.

Comment: Coroutines can only be launched from a CoroutineScope. A `runBlocking` creates its own scope, which becomes the receiver of its lambda function, so that’s why you can launch from inside it. Since a Composable must not cause side effects except within an Effect, you use LaunchedEffect if you want to run a coroutine for a side effect. If you want to launch a coroutine in a click listener, you can use `rememberCoroutineScope()` to create a scope for that, since a listener is not a Composable and can have side effects. [More info](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Comment: You can also use `produceState` to run a coroutine that fetches state, but state is not suitable for navigation.